# How to get Integrator Key for docusign

Tags: docusign

I am having a
Demo credentials and Live credentials

When I login into my demo account and go to

API->Already have an Integrator Key and ready to move to Production?

To Start with certification process link gives me "This document has been suspended and is not currently active. Please contact the sender."

May I know how can I proceed to get Integrator Key.